# Requests fails with SSLError 'failed to allocate SSL context'

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, python-requests, urllib2

I'm trying to use requests to make a POST request to a RESTful API. My code is very straightforward:

```
import json
import requests
import subprocess

url = 'https://api.host.name?key=MY_API_KEY'
post_data = {'parameter': 'value'}
try:
    requests.post(url, json = post_data, verify=False) # Fails Frequently ...
except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
    post_data_str = json.dumps(post_data)
    curl_cli = "curl -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Accept: application/json\" -X POST -d '%s' %s" %(post_data_str, url)
    output = subprocess.check_output(curl_cli , shell=True) # Works every time!
```

The code sometimes works but most typically it fails with error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.host.name', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: api.host.name (Caused by SSLError(SSLError('failed to allocate SSL context',),))

The error appears to be random, i.e. sometimes it fails the first time I run the code, sometimes after a couple of successful requests. When I execute the same request from Postman (an application to issue requests to REST APIs) it always succeeds.

My `requests` version is 2.18.4 and I'm using Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

EDIT:

I also tried `urllib2` with similar results. The code is:

```
import json
import urllib2

url = 'https://api.host.name?key=MY_API_KEY'
post_dict = {'parameter': 'value'}
post_data = json.dumps(post_dict)
clen = len(post_data)
req = urllib2.Request(url, post_data, {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': clen})
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response = f.read()
```

The error is essentially the same:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 429, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 447, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1241, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1167, in do_open
    h = http_class(host, timeout=req.timeout, **http_conn_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1262, in __init__
    context = ssl._create_default_https_context()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 411, in create_default_context
    context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 337, in __new__
    self = _SSLContext.__new__(cls, protocol)
ssl.SSLError: ('failed to allocate SSL context',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, here is what I can offer:

1. Try using python3 if you are not as I have heard people getting issues like this from 2.7(Likely not your solution)
2. Try implementing a sleep function (import sleep) and give it a timeout to wait in between requests as you may be requesting too many API calls in an allocated time and the system may be "banning" your machine from accessing the API.
3. Validate your OpenSSL library version and update if necessary.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems (2) isn't a problem because my requests through Postman never fail. I added `sleep` just in case but didn't help. Unfortunately (1) isn't possible because I'm using a module that only works with Python 2.x and it looks like I have the latest version of python-openssl. Still a mystery!

Comment: Are you able to get a more accurate stack trace to the issue? Perhaps there is a cipher issue, check this link to see more about what SSLContext is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634258/what-is-ssl-context

Comment: I edited the question to include the error message from urllib2, which is essentially the same. What I ended up doing is to catch the exception and call `curl` from the command line (see my edit), which works every time ...