# Preparing two application data with same SSL_CTX state

Tags: c++, c, ssl, optimization, openssl

Is there a way to prepare two application data records with same SSL_CTX state (same sequence number and cipher state) and then write only one of them to fd? Or, as an alternative, any methods for SSL_CTX state export/import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSL context (SSL_CTX) is not the state of the current TLS session. It is instead only a common set of settings which can be used for multiple TLS sessions. It does not contain any sequence numbers or exchanged keys yet. See [What is SSL context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634258/what-is-ssl-context/31634309).

What you probably mean is the state of the SSL session itself which contains the cipher suite to use, the sequence numbers, the encryption keys etc. This session does not get prepared up-front but it is the result of a TLS handshake between client and server. Insofar it is coupled to the underlying connection where the TLS handshake was done (usually a TCP connection, but could in theory also be any data stream).

I'm not aware of any method offered by OpenSSL to serialize and unserialize the full state of a running SSL session, i.e. everything which is needed to continue with an existing TLS connection. What can be done is to fork the current process in which case the child process will have an exact copy of the session state. Not the the states in child and parent are not synchronized, i.e. only one of these should interact with the SSL session.

What can also be done is to get the `SSL_SESSION` object. This does not describe in full the state of the current SSL session (i.e. no sequence numbers) but it includes things like the cipher and the encryption keys. This object can actually be serialized using [i2d_SSL_SESSION](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/i2d_SSL_SESSION.html) and can be used to resume the same session within another process - provided that the server supports it. The same `SSL_SESSION` can even be used by multiple connections at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. After all I switched to GnuTLS, it provides useful gnutls_record_get_state() / gnutls_record_set_state() functions.